# Como fazer o CRUD pelo model no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Podemos fazer no `controller` os método `save()` o `find($id)` o `update()` e `create()`. Como poderia fazer em que o `Model` tivesse essa **responsabilidade**?

Comment: O Eloquent já proponhe esse modelo, se poderia explicar melhor sua duvida

Comment: Então, no controller eu tenho uma função do eloquent chamado update certo?
em vez de chamar o método update(); no controlar não seria melhor passar esse método la para o model e chamar no controller o método de update?

Comment: não... Isso deve ter uma razão porque duplicar funcionalidade sem necessidade é um erro conceitual. A sua pergunta parece mau formulada, talvez com uma edição melhore o contexo.

Answer (score 2):

Sua pergunta está meio vaga, mas acho que entendi sua dúvida.

> Como poderia fazer em que o Model tivesse essa responsabilidade?

O model *já tem* essa responsabilidade. É o Eloquent que sabe realizar a busca com `find`, criar uma nova instância com `create` e atualizá-la com `save` ou `update` (tem o `delete` também né).

**A responsabilidade dos métodos dos Controllers é outra.** Eles devem orquestrar as várias etapas da interação com algum comando CRUD. Elas são normalmente compostas de:

1. Autorização para realizar a operação
2. Validação do pedido
3. Execução do comando CRUD
4. Envio da resposta (view, json, etc.)

Para cada uma dessas etapas, o Laravel apresenta algumas várias ferramentas:

1. *Autorização:* Gates, Policies e método `$this->authorize` do controller
2. *Validação:* Validators com Validation Rules e Custom Validation
3. *CRUD:* Eloquent model ou QueryBuilder e DB Facade
4. *Resposta:* Views com Blade ou formatação automática de JSONs

Claro que essa é uma visão simplificada, mas a ideia é deixar claro que **o papel do Controller é orquestrar essas etapas e o papel do Model é apenas uma delas**.

Comment: Bacana, mais deixa eu te perguntar, vamos supor. Eu faço um método no model chamado de store que recebe n parâmetros store($id, $request)
e no contrôler eu somente passo os dados vindo do request para o metodo store no model Tipo
$store = new Cadastro();
$store->store($id, $request) onde esse id vem do metodo que esta no controller que passo para o metodo que esta no model e la no model eu chamo o save(). e retorno true ou false. assim distribui melhor o código e limpa o controller. O que vc acha?

Comment: @NatanMelo, para ficar mais fácil pra td mundo, vou pedir que você edite a pergunta incluindo esse cenário seu com ao menos o método do controller e o método do model exemplificados. Pode ser? Aí expando minha resposta de acordo. Valeeu